# unable to EXPORT data from current open web page using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, data-extraction

I want to automate my delivery status for my regular courier from various service provider like Blue Dart.

I have Docket Numbers; I tried the same using VBA but it is unable to fetch data from webpage.

My code enter the Docket number from cell in home page, then it redirects to other page where delivery status is mentioned in table.

```
Sub GetCourseList()

 Dim IE As Object
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 Dim IEWindows           As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
 Dim IEwindow            As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Dim IEDocument          As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim BreadcrumbDiv       As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection

 Set IEWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

'create new instance of IE. use reference to return current open IE if
'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar.
  IE.Navigate "http://www.bluedart.com/maintracking.html"
'go to web page listed inside quotes
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend
  IE.Document.All("numbers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
   Application.SendKeys "~"

    Dim URL As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    For Each IEwindow In IEWindows
    If InStr(IEwindow.LocationURL, "your URL or some unique string") <> 0 Then  ' Found it
    Set IEDocument = IEwindow.Document

    URL = IEwindow.LocationURL

    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=Range("F1"))

         With qt
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .Name = "bluedart"
        .FieldNames = True
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: We don't have values from your sheet to test it and there is no mention what exactly doesn't work. Do you have an error in some line? Also use `Option Explicit` on top of the procedure, `While IE.busy Or IE.Readystate <>4`, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").value2` and avoid `SendKeys` as it is not reliable. These are only good practices, not a direct solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Eg of Docket Number  for tracking 50419480764  or 50419669171; I am not getting any error but it even doesn't fetch the data as if it is blank

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not attempt to interact with a page generated after entering Docket Number and confirming in any way. It could be done by:

Emulating browser interaction, can be Internet Explorer: click "Go" element on the page after Docket Number has been entered and use:

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.Readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
```

It can also be achieved by creating POST request with proper parameters, including Docket Number.

Even after this is achieved, it still won't be possible to get data by query from this page, as its URL is this:

http://www.bluedart.com/servlet/RoutingServlet

Try to open this link. Nothing will display, because content of this URL is generated via POST method and parameters needed to generate content properly are not included in URL.

Instead of query, data can be accessed via finding HTML elements, such as tables, in HTML document for both methods I've mentioned.

Comment: ,Thanks for reply.
Ya that's the problem since it is calling via a post method.So i wanted to get the data from the currently open Page in IE.
How can i achieve that.